# Concatenate and 4-up Postscript files

Tags: postscript

I have a directory with 79 one-page PS files. They were made with gnuplot. I would like to print them, but--due to their volume--need to put several on one sheet. Ideally I'd like 4 per side (8 per sheet).

I tried:

```
a2ps -4 -o output.ps *.ps
```

(also tried with `--file-align=virtual`)

whose tail end reads:

```
[plot_Viscount_Hamilton.csv.ps (ps, delegated to PsNup): 5 pages on 2 sheets]
[plot_Viscount_Reidhaven.csv.ps (ps, delegated to PsNup): 5 pages on 2 sheets]
[plot_William_Gibson_Graig_M_P_.csv.ps (ps, delegated to PsNup): 5 pages on 2 sheets]
[Total: 312 pages on 78 sheets] saved into the file `output.ps'
```

but `output.ps` contains one four-part page, the top-left quadrant of which contains one of the original PS files (the other three quadrants are empty).

I also tried fooling around with pstops and psjoin, but didn't get very far. Any advice?

PS: To put this in context, my dataflow is like this:

Source files in ABC Notation `==Lisp Program==>` Lisp object model `==Other Lisp Program==>` CSV files `==gnuplot==>` PS files `== ?? ==>` Combined PS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `a2ps` is having difficulty because it doesn't process the postscript natively, but instead uses a *delegate* program. So it treats postscript files essentially as images, and inserts the file (with some small wrapping) more or less directly into its output. `a2ps` really shines at pretty-printing source code, but concatenation and N-up compositing of already "rendered" ps documents is a little outside of its proper scope, IMO. It's the wrong tool for *this* job.

The tool for making 4up versions of postscript files is `psnup`, part of `psutils`, for which I found a nice link [here](http://www.novell.com/documentation/suse91/suselinux-adminguide/html/ch06s08.html).

---

Duh. I guess the given error output clearly shows what I "guessed" above. The link goes into details, but I'll summarize here. You need to take control of how the 1-page documents are rotated and concatenated (using `ps2ps`) before they are fed to `psnup`.

Comment: `psmerge -oconcatenated.ps *.ps && psnup -4 concatenated.ps output.ps` did the trick. Thanks so much!